# Hacer scroll en dispositivos móviles sobre elementos dragables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Me encuentro trasteando con la librería **Jquery-UI** más concretamente con las funciones de **Drag & Drop** y me topé con un problemilla. Aparentemente esta no funciona en dispositivos móviles, con los **touch events**.

Buscando encontré otra librería que complementa a **Jquery-UI** (*jQuery UI Touch Punch*), añadiéndole los necesarios **touch events**. Hasta ahí el contexto.

Ahora me meteré con el problema que estoy tratando de solucionar. Lo que necesito es que se pueda hacer **scroll** sobre los elementos **dragables** sin que que con ello el elemento se llegue a "agarrar", para poder navegar por el listado de **itemns**.

A través de la opción `delay` que tienen los elementos **dragables**, he conseguido que dichos elementos no reaccionen al dragado hasta pasado un segundo (para poder diferenciar entre si quiero "agarrarlo" o por el contrario lo que quiero es hacer **scroll**), pero lo que no consigo es la parte de hacer **scroll** pasando el dedo por estos elementos, ya que esta función queda deshabilitada.

**¿Existe alguna opción de los elementos dragables que me permita conseguir lo que necesito?** En caso negativo, **¿habría alguna manera de conseguir lo que necesito aunque pase por programarla a pelo?**

```js
$(function() {
    $("#contenedor-articulos ul").sortable({
        revert: true,
        delay: 1000,
        scroll: false,
        stack: "#contenedor-grupo",
        opacity: 0.35,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            //let elemento = ui.item;
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //console.log('Se detiene');
        }
    });

    $("#contenedor-grupos ul").sortable({
        revert: true,
        delay: 1000,
        scroll: false,
        stack: "#contenedor-articulos",
        opacity: 0.35,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            //let elemento = ui.item;
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //console.log('Se detiene');
        }
    });

    $("#contenedor-grupos").droppable({
        accept: "#contenedor-articulos li",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            let elemento = ui.draggable;
            let contenedor = $(this).find('ul'); 

            elemento.removeAttr('style');
            elemento.clone().appendTo(contenedor);
            elemento.remove(); 
        }
    });

    $("#contenedor-articulos").droppable({
        accept: "#contenedor-grupos li",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            let elemento = ui.draggable;
            let contenedor = $(this).find('ul'); 

            elemento.removeAttr('style');
            elemento.clone().appendTo(contenedor);
            elemento.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.listado-articulos {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.listado-articulos > li {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;
}

.grupo, #contenedor-articulos {
    background-color: orange;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 204px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
            <div id="contenedor-titulo" class="row">
                <h1>Prueba Drag and Drop</h1> 
            </div>
            
            <div id="contenedor-aticulos-grupos" class="row">
                <section id="seccion-listado-articulos" class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                    <h2>Artículos</h2>
                    <div id="contenedor-articulos">
                        <ul class="listado-articulos">
                            <li data-articulo="articulo-1">Artículo 1</li>
                            <li data-articulo="articulo-2">Artículo 2</li>
                            <li data-articulo="articulo-3">Artículo 3</li>
                            <li data-articulo="articulo-4">Artículo 4</li>
                            <li data-articulo="articulo-5">Artículo 5</li>
                            <li data-articulo="articulo-6">Artículo 6</li>
                            <li data-articulo="articulo-7">Artículo 7</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
                <section id="seccion-grupos" class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                    <h2>Grupo</h2>
                    <div id="contenedor-grupos">
                        <div class="grupo">
                            <ul class="listado-articulos">
                                
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```